# tough/tricky analytic function issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following scenario that I need help with

```
ID_Number Budget_Period Start_Date End_date   Period_Type
   1         1          2/12/2007  2/11/2008  Annual 
   1         2          3/15/2008  3/14/2009  Annual 
   1         3          4/15/2009  4/14/2010  Annual
   2         1          8/18/2010  8/17/2011  Annual 
   2         2          9/19/2011  9/18/2012  Annual
```

What I need is to make the start and end dates contigous for a given id so that there are no gaps across budget periods for that given id_number ..so for example for ID_Number 1 , the Min(Start_date) is 2/12/2007 and Max(End_date) is 4/14/2010 so the data for each budget period should just be 364 days apart between the start and end dates as shown below

Required output

```
ID_Number Budget_Period Start_Date End_date   Period_Type
   1         1          2/12/2007  2/11/2008  Annual 
   1         2          2/12/2008  2/11/2009  Annual 
   1         3          2/12/2010  4/14/2010  Annual
   2         1          8/18/2010  8/17/2011  Annual
   2         2          8/18/2011  09/18/2012 Annual
```

Can this be done using analytic functions? I am unable to get the required output using the queries I tried..any help would be appreciated

Comment: Post the queries you have tried.

Comment: so what about id 1. in your sample requested output you do have a gap from 2009 to 2010.

Comment: also your 2,2 value is 366 days long again violating what you said that 364 should be max (should that slip into budget period 3?)

Answer (score 1):

if each range is to be 1 year minus a day then shouldn't the output be this?

```
SQL> select id_number, i+1 budget_period, start_date, end_date, 'Annual' period_type
  2    from (select id_number, min(start_date) start_date, max(end_date) end_date from a
  3           group by id_number)
  4         model
  5           partition by (id_number)
  6           dimension by (0 as i)
  7           measures(start_date, end_date, end_date ed)
  8           rules
  9           (start_date[for i from 1 to ceil(months_between(add_months(end_date[0],-12), start_date[0])/12)
 10                       increment 1] = add_months(start_date[0], 12*cv(i)),
 11            end_date[any] = least(ed[0], add_months(start_date[CV()], 12)-1)
 12           )
 13   order by 1,2;

 ID_NUMBER BUDGET_PERIOD START_DAT END_DATE  PERIOD
---------- ------------- --------- --------- ------
         1             1 12-FEB-07 11-FEB-08 Annual
         1             2 12-FEB-08 11-FEB-09 Annual
         1             3 12-FEB-09 11-FEB-10 Annual
         1             4 12-FEB-10 14-APR-10 Annual
         2             1 18-AUG-10 17-AUG-11 Annual
         2             2 18-AUG-11 17-AUG-12 Annual
         2             3 18-AUG-12 18-SEP-12 Annual

7 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not specifying an end date would work -- it's redundant if the next record's start date is the day after.